# why i have the LNK 2019 error in SFML? (With every .lib added)

Tags: c++, sfml

i have a problem with SML. It goes like this: i added the libraries of sfml-graphics.lib, sfml-window.lib, sfml-system.lib and sfml-audio.lib, and their debug variants in the debug too.

[image]
[image]

But when i try this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"..\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Window.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "CosaFea");
    /*while (window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

It jumps 4 LNK2019 errors and 4 external unresolved symbols LNK1120.

[image]

Anyone have any idea of what I can be doing wrong?

Comment: i'm not asking what an external symbol error is, the question it's not duplicated

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] then (including the linker command line) and clearly state in your question why the duplicate doesn't answer your problem please!

Comment: I'm sorry, i will proceed to edit the question

Comment: The reason you have LNK2019 is because the project can't find the source, i.e. your libraries. Go to Linker(Vinculador) -> General -> **Additional Library dependencies**. Add the file path to the SFML libraries folder.